# display HTML content from database with formatting in it

Tags: php, cakephp, sanitization, wmd-editor, html-editor

I have used **[wmd-editor](http://wmd-editor.com/)** in my **[cakephp v1.3](http://cakephp.org)** application.

The config which I have written is as follows:

```
wmd_options = {
            output: "HTML",

            lineLength: 40,

            buttons: "bold italic | link blockquote code image | ol ul heading hr",

            autostart: true
        };
```

When I submit the form the HTML in the wmd enabled textarea is saved in the database with `htmlentities()` done to the text then it is decoded with `html_entity_decode()` method automatically.
but the text is displayed as it is including the HTML coding like this

`<p><strong>hello dear friends</strong></p>\n\n<pre><code>I want to make sure that everything that you type is visible clearly.\nadasfafas\n</code></pre>\n\n<blockquote>\n <p>sadgsagasdgxcbxcbxc</p>\n</blockquote>\n\n<p><em>sadfgsgasdsgasgs</em></p>\n\n<p><b><a href="http://kumu.in">this is the link</a></b></p>`

Please help me solve this problem

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried without `htmlentities()` and `html_entity_decode()`? Sounds like the input might already be encoded (ie. `&gt;` becomes `&amp;gt;` which then displays `<` on your page rather than in the source).

Comment: Yeah you are right... I figured that out already... but facing a different problem now. :-( (populating the decoded text back into the wmd-input so that all the formatting is preserved and visible to the end user)
actually I am using Sanitize::clean method of cake php sanitize class.
This automatically does htmlentities to the data posted to the database.

Answer (score 1):

For sanitization against XSS its generally better to save raw HTML in database without modification and sanitize at the time of output/display. Use [Sanitize](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1183/Data-Sanitization) core library.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have set the option as `output: "HTML",` is is saved as html, however you can use the **[`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)** function to remove html tags from the text.

Comment: and the formatting will be lost then.... I want to render that formatting with some allowable tags not completely removing the tags